# angular routing in ie8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, routes

I have an angular app at url www.myapp.com/office/tarif
My route config:

```
$routeProvider.
  when('/', {
  templateUrl: '/angular/template/index',
  controller: 'TarifCtrl',
}).
  when('/order', {
  templateUrl: '/angular/template/order',
  controller: 'TarifCtrl',
});
```

HTML5mode set to false. When i go to www.myapp.com/office/tarif it adds #/ to end of url and in chrome works fine, but in ie8 it's not rendering template. If i go to www.myapp.com/office/tarif#/ it works fine too. 
When i go to www.myapp.com/office/tarif/order it just renders index template again in chrome (and render nothing in ie8). 
I used html5mode earlier and it works fine but now i need to support ie8 so i need help.

Comment: Check the doc for IE compatibility: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie and compare your code, it might be a little something. Also look for a javascript error in the dev console (F12).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular Views/Routes in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533416/angular-views-routes-in-ie8)